# Seeking border data which is classified as Coastal and Land?

Tags: data, borders

I am trying to operate regressions over two parameters - (1) Ratio of length of coastal border to land border (2) Average Military Expenditure through 1996-2016 for each country.

For parameter (2) will use the database given by SIPRI(Stockholm Peace Institution) which is available in following link : https://www.sipri.org/databases/milex

However, since I am an quite novice to the field of Geographic informations, so keep losing my times to find the required and proper data for para (1).

For clarification **coastal border** means measured total length of border where it faces with **sea**  while land border means measured total length of border where it faces with **land**.

I prefer the csv type of database, but the format would not be big problem and also I am willing to handle and experience some geo-specific data formats too.

**Where could I get the border data which is classified as Coastal and Land?**

**I am basically using Python with NumPy and Matpolib.**

Comment: Welcome! Please take the community tour here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to include details that will help us know what you need. What software are you using? What is your question, in particular?

Comment: @BERA sorry for ambiguity. Has clarified it.

Comment: @MaryBeth sorry. Had disambiguated OP.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a ready-made dataset that fits your requirements.

An alternative could be Natural Earth. They have borders (total and land): http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors.
Costal will be the difference between total and land.

So while this is certainly possible, some data wrangling will be involved.

Comment: Does total border(length) consist of Land, Coastal, Riverside? I don't know the clear terms used in Geography.

Comment: I was referring to the circumference of the country polygons as "total". The circumference is a value that can be calculated using GIS

Comment: I have a question. If I just use the coastal one as "Total - Land", would it problem do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The borders in Natural Earth could work as per Underdarks excellent suggestion.  However, I think they are based on GSHHS data which is less accurate than OSM's coastlines which are available [here](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines).  It all depends on the resolution you need.

There is a link on the page to land polygons and water polygons.  So you could buffer the coastlines and clip with water polygons to give you areas within a set distance of the coast (depending on your definition of coastal).  Doing this globally will be intense depending on your machine but is doable (perhaps run overnight).